# How do I remove HOME from breadcrumb

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, breadcrumbs

I am using Drupal 6.17 and want to get rid of "HOME" in the breadcrumb output...

eg:

$breadcrumb= PRODUCTS // SOFTWARE // FEATURES

instead of

HOME // PRODUCTS // SOFTWARE // FEATURES

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the breadcrumb in your theme's template.php file:

```
/**
 * Return a themed breadcrumb trail.
 *
 * @param $breadcrumb
 *   An array containing the breadcrumb links.
 * @return a string containing the breadcrumb output.
 */
function phptemplate_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    array_shift($breadcrumb); // Removes the Home item
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' › ', $breadcrumb) .'</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Drupal 7 version:

```
/**
 * Get rid of Home in breadcrumb trail.
 */
function <themename>_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    array_shift($breadcrumb); // Removes the Home item
    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Hide 'Home' Breadcrumb for Drupal 8

(Replace `yourtheme` with your theme's actual machine name...)

---

### Option 1: fast and simple theme preprocess

Add the following to your theme's `yourtheme.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for `breadcrumb.html.twig`.
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables){

  // Remove 'Home' from breadcrumb trail.
  if (count($variables['breadcrumb'])) {
    array_shift($variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
}
```

---

### Or Option 2: a checkbox option in theme settings

[image: Screenshot demonstrating what the theme settings option looks like in the Drupal Admin Appearance UI]

Add the following to your theme's `theme-settings.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 */
function yourtheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {

  $form['theme_settings']['hide_home_breadcrumb'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'checkbox',
    '#title'         => t('Hide <em>Home</em> in breadcrumb trail'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('hide_home_breadcrumb', 'yourtheme'),
  );

}
```

Add the following to your theme's `yourtheme.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for `breadcrumb.html.twig`.
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables){

  // Remove 'Home' from breadcrumb trail.
  if (!empty(theme_get_setting('hide_home_breadcrumb', 'yourtheme')) && count($variables['breadcrumb'])) {
    array_shift($variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
}
```

If you want the Home button to be disabled by default when the theme is installed, add the following to your theme's `yourtheme.settings.yml`:

```
# Hide 'Home' in breadcrumb trail by default.
hide_home_breadcrumb: 1
```

If you're working with an existing site, and are using Drupal Configuration Syncing with Drupal 8, you should also add/modify the `yourtheme.settings.yml` file in the sync directory, and run `drush cim sync`.

---

### Or Option 3: a more nuanced theme setting

In some cases, a site design might call for hiding the *Home* link if it is the only item in the breadcrumb trail, and **when there are other items in the breadcrumb trail to leave *Home* in the breadcrumb trail.**

[image: Screenshot demonstrating a more nuanced theme setting with 3 radio button options to select home breadcrumb visibility options]

Here's how to implement the radio buttons depicted above:

Add the following to your theme's `theme-settings.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 */
function yourtheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {

  $form['breadcrumbs'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('Breadcrumb'),
    '#open' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['breadcrumbs']['hide_home_breadcrumb'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => [
      '0' => 'Show <em>Home</em> in breadcrumb trail (Drupal’s default behavior)',
      '1' => 'Remove <em>Home</em> from breadcrumb trail',
      '2' => 'Remove <em>Home</em> when it is the only breadcrumb in trail',
    ],
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('hide_home_breadcrumb', 'yourtheme'),
  );

}
```

Add the following to your theme's `yourtheme.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for `breadcrumb.html.twig`.
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables){

  // Remove 'Home' from breadcrumb trail based on theme settings variable.
  //
  // Possible values:
  // - 0: do not remove
  // - 1: remove
  // - 2: remove if its the only item
  $hide_home_breadcrumb = theme_get_setting('hide_home_breadcrumb', 'yourtheme');
  if ($hide_home_breadcrumb == '1' && count($variables['breadcrumb'])) {
    array_shift($variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
  elseif ($hide_home_breadcrumb == '2' && count($variables['breadcrumb']) == 1) {
    array_shift($variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
}
```

If you want the Home button to be disabled by default when the theme is installed, add the following to your theme's `yourtheme.settings.yml`:

```
# Remove 'Home' in breadcrumb trail if its the only item.
hide_home_breadcrumb: '2'
```

If you're working with an existing site, and are using Drupal Configuration Syncing with Drupal 8, you should also add/modify the `yourtheme.settings.yml` file in the sync directory, and run `drush cim sync`.

Answer (score 1):

[Theming Breadcrumb Output HTML](http://drupal.org/node/339540)
[Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 0):

In templated.php ask if "Home page" and be language specific. Take out ( **&& $language_url->languag**e and **global $language_url;**) if you don't need language look up. Also change "/htdocs/drupal/de" in "href" to appropriate URL.

```
function _YOUR_THEME_NAME_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
    global $language_url;

          if (drupal_is_front_page()){
              return;
              } elseif(!empty($breadcrumb) && $language_url->language == 'de') {
              $breadcrumb[0] = '<a href="/htdocs/drupal/de">STARTSEITE</a>';
                $breadcrumb = implode(' | ', $breadcrumb);
                return $breadcrumb;
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have path breadcrumbs module installed. Go to structure > Path breadcrumbs > path breadcrumbs settings, then check the "Hide breadcrumbs navigation for single breadcrumb", save configuration, refresh page. Done.